# Installing Tizen Studio on Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, tizen-studio

I am experiencing problems installing Tizen Studio 2.1 on Xubuntu 16.04

Following the steps on the [Tizen Developer Website](https://developer.tizen.org/development/tizen-studio/download/installing-tizen-studio) and when I tried to execute the web-installer I got the following error in my terminal:

```
faebl@faeblTux:~/Downloads$ chmod +x ./web-ide_Tizen_Studio_2.0_usa_ubuntu-64.bin 
faebl@faeblTux:~/Downloads$ ./web-ide_Tizen_Studio_2.0_usa_ubuntu-64.bin 
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/faebl/.package-manager’: Permission denied
./web-ide_Tizen_Studio_2.0_usa_ubuntu-64.bin: line 155: /home/faebl/.package-manager/run/tizensdk_20180104135257/checksum: No such file or directory

gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: /home/faebl/.package-manager/run/tizensdk_20180104135257: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
cat: /home/faebl/.package-manager/run/tizensdk_20180104135257/checksum: No such file or directory
 The download file appears to be corrupted. 
 Please do not attempt to install this archive file.
```

I then tried to install Tizen with the help of [this tutorial](https://devtizen.wordpress.com/2013/06/01/how-to-install-tizen-sdk-in-ubuntu/), but that gave me the same error.
I also tried to download the installer from different mirrors or other sources, with the same result.

Can anybody please point me into the right direction for installing the software?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I have found the answer to this and 2 other problems I had when I combined the errors of these:
Some directories of my home folder /home/faebl were not owned by the user faebl:faebl.

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/182561/268817) did the trick and resolved all three errors at once.
I hope this helps anybody...

Cheers..